# Automatically identifying ultimate and penultimate columns as variable in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, variables, multiple-columns

I am trying to automize a part of the following code that I introduced [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31142884/using-first-row-as-variable-with-python). As it is, the code works and achieves my desired final result. However, one of the variables is semi-automatic and I would like to automize it.

This is the code that I have to transfer raw data into an input file.

```
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-

import logging
from optparse import OptionParser
import sys

def main():
    LEVELS = {'debug': logging.DEBUG,
              'info': logging.INFO,
              'warning': logging.WARNING,
              'error': logging.ERROR,
              'critical': logging.CRITICAL}

    usage = "usage: arff automate [options]\n ."
    parser = OptionParser(usage=usage, version="%prog 1.0")

    #Defining options   
    parser.add_option("-l", "--log", dest="level_name", default="info", help="choose the logging level: debug, info, warning, error, critical")    

    #Parsing arguments
    (options, args) = parser.parse_args()

    #Mandatory arguments    
    if len(args) != 1:
        parser.error("incorrect number of arguments")

    inputPath = args[0]


    # Start program ------------------

    with open(inputPath, "r") as f:
        strip = str.strip
        split = str.split
        data = [line.strip().split() for line in f]


###############################################################
## Below Here is the part that I need to modify
###############################################################


    numAtts = len(data[0])
    logging.info(" Number of attributes : "+str(numAtts) )

    print "@relation 'o_wekaarff.arff'"

    for e in range(numAtts):
        if e < 5:
            print "@ATTRIBUTE 'att [{0}]' numeric".format(data[0][e])
        elif e == 5:
            print "@ATTRIBUTE 'att [{0}]' binary".format(data[0][e])
        elif e == 6:
            print "@ATTRIBUTE 'att [{0}]' string".format(data[0][e])

###############################################################
## Above Here is the part that I need to modify
###############################################################

    classSet = set()
    for e in data:
        classSet.add(e[-1])
    print ""

    print "@data"

    next(iter(data))
    for item in data[1:]:
        print ",".join(item[0:])



if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

This is the raw data I have used:

```
F1  F2  F3  F4  F5  {0,1}   STRING
7209    3004    15302   5203    2   1   EXAMPLEA
6417    3984    16445   5546    15  1   EXAMPLEB
8822    3973    23712   7517    18  0   EXPAMPLEC
```

The result obtained is the following:

```
@relation 'o_wekaarff.arff'
@ATTRIBUTE 'att [F1]' numeric
@ATTRIBUTE 'att [F2]' numeric
@ATTRIBUTE 'att [F3]' numeric
@ATTRIBUTE 'att [F4]' numeric
@ATTRIBUTE 'att [F5]' numeric
@ATTRIBUTE 'att [{0,1}]' binary
@ATTRIBUTE 'att [STRING]' string

@data
7209,3004,15302,5203,2,1,EXAMPLEA
6417,3984,16445,5546,15,1,EXAMPLEB
8822,3973,23712,7517,18,0,EXPAMPLEC
```

However, this is sample data. In the future, it will be possible that I have thousands of columns. Because of that, I would like the script to automatically recognize what are the ultimate and penultimate columns - in order to not manually define what number that they are in, as it is done currently with `e`.

Is there a `pythonic` way to do this, without having to manually define the number of columns that is later printed with a specific variable, as indicated in the output example?

Comment: Why don't you just get the length of the row with `len()`, and compare accordingly?

Comment: I already have that information in the variable `numAtts`... It was not clear to me how I can use that to identify the different levels of information that I need dynamically.

Comment: You could iterate over `data[0][:-2]` (i.e. *"all but the last two items"*) as numeric data, then `data[0][-2]` and `data[0][-1]` separately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following approach could be added into your example code. It first reads the first row into a list (which can be any length). It assigns numeric format to all but the last two entries. It then assigns binary and string to the remaining two entries. There is no restriction (within reason) on the number of initial columns you might have.

It then processes the remaining lines into the format you gave.

```
import csv

with open(inputPath, "r") as f_input:
    csv_input = csv.reader(f_input, delimiter=" ", skipinitialspace=True)
    first_row = csv_input.next()

    print "@relation 'o_wekaarff.arff'" 

    for col in first_row[:-2]:
        print "@ATTRIBUTE 'att [{0}]' numeric".format(col)

    for col, attribute in zip(first_row[-2:], ["binary", "string"]):
        print "@ATTRIBUTE 'att [{0}]' {1}".format(col, attribute)

    print "\n@data"

    for row in csv_input:
        print ",".join(row)
```

Based on your raw input, this gives the output as follows:

```
@relation 'o_wekaarff.arff'
@ATTRIBUTE 'att [F1]' numeric
@ATTRIBUTE 'att [F2]' numeric
@ATTRIBUTE 'att [F3]' numeric
@ATTRIBUTE 'att [F4]' numeric
@ATTRIBUTE 'att [F5]' numeric
@ATTRIBUTE 'att [{0,1}]' binary
@ATTRIBUTE 'att [STRING]' string

@data
7209,3004,15302,5203,2,1,EXAMPLEA
6417,3984,16445,5546,15,1,EXAMPLEB
8822,3973,23712,7517,18,0,EXPAMPLEC
```

Answer (score 1):

```
data[0][-2:]
```

This will give you the last two elements of a list (if they exist).